# R leaflet - cannot export map

Tags: html, r, leaflet, openstreetmap, r-leaflet

I plot a route on a map using R and leaflet :

```
ct <- read.csv("fl1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

m <- leaflet(ct, incl.data=TRUE) %>% addTiles() 
m %>% addPolylines(~longitude, ~latitude, color = "red", weight = 4
```

RStudio plots exactly what I want:
[image: RStudio plot]

However, I cannot export it as an HTML.

I tried:

1. use Export-> Save as web Page
2. the saveWidget function:

   saveWidget(m, file="m.html")

   saveWidget(m, '1F.html', selfcontained = FALSE)

   saveWidget(m, '1T.html', selfcontained = TRUE)

In all above cases I get an html file, but when I try to open them using Chrome, Firefox and IE, the best I can get is only the route and not the map:

[image: Browser output]

Comment: Take a look at the browser's developer / error console output.

Comment: what do you mean? my RStudio console doesn't create ane warnings or errors whatsoever. I do not use any other tool.

Comment: You mentioned opening this HTML file in your browser. Your browser can produce error output, too.

Comment: ok,  I get an error: 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND', and: GET file://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/1/1.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: `file://c.tile.openstreetmap.org` is wrong and should be `http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org` instead. No idea where to fix this, though.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and salexir's answer proved to be a good starting point. The bug indeed seems to be in the `addTiles()` function.

Replacing it with `addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")` worked for me. Explore ?addProviderTiles for more options.

Comment: @erculeo you're welcome. Please accept the answer (green tick on the left) if you found that it solved your problem :)

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked. I used addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik")

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the addTiles() function, which you can bypass by recreating your own function. See kgavhane702's workaround here: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/192